# web app to return boolean result to html from checking data in spreadsheet

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have html page and script for check, the project deployed like web app

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CLR: PACKING</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
       integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>      
</head>
<body>
    <div class="conteiner">
        <form novalidate>
                <h6 class="title">PACKING</h6>
            <div class="dws-input">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <button id="del" type="button">&lt;======RESET</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" novalidate id="tLogin" name= "username" placeholder= "Логин:" autofocus > 
                        <label for="tLogin">Login:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  novalidate id="tTable" name= "text" placeholder= "Номер стола:" >
                        <label for="tTable">Table:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input type="text"  novalidate class="form-control" id="tOrder" name= "text" placeholder= "Заказ:" >
                    <label for="tOrder">Order:</label>
                </div> 
            </div>  
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <?!= include("index-js"); ?>

</body>



</html>
```

In included "index-js.html" I have this

```html
<script>

inputs.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressFunction);

function keyPressFunction(ev) {

  if (ev.code !== 'Enter') return;

  if (ev.target.id == "tLogin"){
    var findLogin = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).searchLogins(ev.target.value);
    console.log(ev.target.value);
    console.log(findLogin);
  } 

  for (const i of formControl) {
    if (i.value === '') {
      i.nextElementSibling.focus();
      break;
    }
  }
}

function onSuccess(findLogin) {
   if(!findLogin) {return false} else {return true}
 }


</script>
```

this code send question to the apps script server where I have this:

```js
function searchLogins(login){
        
  let sheetApp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheetTo = sheetApp.getSheetByName("SISTEM");
  let findingRLGN = sheetTo.getRange("A:A").getValues();
    for (let i = 0; i < findingRLGN.length; i++){
      if(findingRLGN[i].indexOf(login)!==-1){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Totally I need to return the true/false result from onSuccess to var findLogin for next actions. May be here I need not this "withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)"? Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible reason about 'delay' may be due to the ineffective code.

`getRange("A:A")` would also get the rows that are blank.

For example, a default sheet has 1000 rows and it would get `A1:A1000`.

May be you would change to `getRange(1, 1, sheetTo.getLastRow(), 1)` or break the `for` loop when the cell is blank (in case there is no blank cell in between).

However, the following change may be most effective (may be can integrate with `getLastRow`)

```js
function searchLogins(login){
  let sheetApp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheetTo = sheetApp.getSheetByName("SISTEM");
  let findingRLGN = sheetTo.getRange("A:A").getValues().flat();
  return findingRLGN.indexOf(login) !== -1;
}
```

Comment: thank you and sorry for my "children's" script. Can you explain me, what does "flat"? Can I  use this without cycles for search data in range?

Comment: Yes, that's why I have removed it. [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) convert 2d array into 1d array such that you can find with `indexOf` without iterating it.

Answer (score 1):

[google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

> google.script.run is an asynchronous client-side JavaScript API

Your need a handler to handle the result.

Also the two log lines should be put in it also.

```js
var findLogin;
function onSuccess(_findLogin) {
    console.log(ev.target.value);
    console.log(_findLogin);
    findLogin = _findLogin;
 }
```

Comment: @ idfurw thank you. If I put onSuccess into function keyPressFunction may be it will work? I forgot than onSuccess is outside from this function

Comment: It is asynchronous, you should not do that and also it should not work.

Comment: @ idfurw but the answer from apps script returns delayed. May be you know how to make that more quickly?

Comment: As I am telling the third time. It is [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous). To achieve what you are saying, you need to convert it into a `promise` and do `await`. Please try yourself first and create a new question if you  need help.