# convert asynchronous onSuccess into a promise and do await

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have html page with inputs

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CLR: PACKING</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
       integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>      
    <?!= include("index-css"); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="conteiner">
        <form novalidate>
                <h6 class="title">PACKING</h6>
            <div class="dws-input">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <button id="del" type="button">&lt;RESET</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" novalidate id="tLogin" name= "username" placeholder= "Логин:" autofocus > 
                        <label for="tLogin">Login:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  novalidate id="tTable" name= "text" placeholder= "Номер стола:" >
                        <label for="tTable">Table:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input type="text"  novalidate class="form-control" id="tOrder" name= "text" placeholder= "Заказ:" >
                    <label for="tOrder">Order:</label>
                </div> 
            </div>  
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <?!= include("index-js"); ?>

</body>



</html>f
```

In include(index-js.html) I wrote this

```html
<script>
  var curInpID;
  var findData;

function keyPressFunction(ev) {

  var inputData = ev.target.value;

  if (ev.code !== 'Enter') return;

  curInpID = ev.target.id;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).searchData(inputData);

  console.log(findData); //result onSuccess here

  for (const i of formControl) {
    if (i.value === '') {
      i.nextElementSibling.focus();
      break;
    }
  }
}

function onSuccess(_findData) {
  findData = _findData;
}




</script>
```

onSuccess goes to apps script, check value at input there and return true/false in findData

```js
function searchData(data){
  
    for (let i = 0; i < arrLogins.length; i++){
      if(arrLogins[i].indexOf(login)!==-1){
        firstValid = true;
        return firstValid;
      }
    }
    firstValid = false;
    return firstValid;
  
}
```

Because of onSuccess is asynchronous, this way works slowly and sometimes returns wrong value to the findData. In the previous topic, a colleague suggested to me to convert it into a promise and do await.

I found some examples with async, await and promise on this site, but I can't understand, what I need to transform here. Please, help me! Thank you!

Comment: I haven't found a way of promisifying `google.script.run` unfortunately. So you need to either adopt the callback paradigm or fire custom events once `onSuccess()` executes

Comment: about paradigm I don't understand totally. It means no way?

Comment: Why do you have to make it sequential? `findData` is not referred anywhere that the execution result should not matter.

Comment: @ idfurw do you mean I did'nt mark where I need return findData for next actions? I made edits on top. Sorry, my mistake

Comment: Whether its in a promise or not, it won't be faster or slower or less asynchronous. Besides, there are many missing parts to your [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Though again, making it into a promise or using async doesn't sound like it will solve your issue. Can you zoom out and describe the context of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @ iansedano  what I need to add to my example? I can give the link of my project for tests if you want. First user write data in input (Login) and click Enter, next in function keyPressFunction google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).searchData(inputData) send question to server with finding data in spreadsheet throw onSuccess and return back true/false to the var findData .

Comment: @ iansedano The problem is - answer from server returns with delay and may be wrong. When the data is right, it can be returned "false" or vice versa. Colleague here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68843074/web-app-to-return-boolean-result-to-html-from-checking-data-in-spreadsheet/68843468?noredirect=1#comment121670921_68843468 said me that it can convert it into a promise and do await. I never did this, so I created this topic. sorry for my English)

Comment: Maybe I have wrongly got what you meant by 'delayed' previously. Do you mean the matching is slow? The execution time is shown in the log. If it is the case, it has nothing to deal with `google.script.run`.

Comment: If you want to make sure every line after the `google.script.run` runs after it. You should promisify it. Or simply move them into the `successHandler`, if the continuing lines are 'simple'.

Comment: @ idfurw  yes I mean slowly matching, sorry for my bad translating)) if previous returned answer in var findData was false and user inserted right data, then answer is whatever false and user has to enter data in input again. can you show me any examples with successHandler, I will try to change to that

Comment: @ idfurw sorry but I can't find the issue, are there any examples with successHandler?

Comment: may be it will possible to set timer for return data from server?

Comment: The question is open, I will be glad any help, sorry, but I'm junior in this

Comment: @DmitriyRudakov  post a link to your test project. At the moment it's not clear what the problem could be as the code you have posted seems incomplete to be able to reproduce it

Comment: @ iansedano yes, I wrote something new in script. This is the checking for correct data at script on servers apps script. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqUmJcTipwKX9Q5m-4dlmXIChp5k1Z98xR2m42GpIT0/edit#gid=0 the checking works correctly but the true/false in var findData matches slowly...

Comment: sorry, any ideas?

Comment: Are you updating the spreadsheet while people are using the webapp? If you are looking to speed up the time response, it's not possible (it takes maybe 5 seconds, yes?). Have you tried debugging what the `inputData` and `curInpID` is? what is the result of this line `var inputData = ev.target.value.replace(/ /g, '');` ? Maybe the issue is the code and not the speed?

Comment: @iansedano inputData is the data user insert in input, in curInpID I send the id of input for checking it in function searchData(inputData, curInpID). ev.target.value.replace(/ /g, '') replace space from input, if user wrote only one space. May be is the code, I'm not the master here...

Comment: @ iansedano may be it's possible to set timeout for 5 seconds after inserting every input? How can we do it?

Comment: it look like there is no way for this question..(((

Comment: I think you need to break up your question into smaller parts and simplify it. Maybe ask various separate questions. At the moment its not clear enough and some parts are in russian it looks like, which I can't understand.

Comment: @iansedano do you think I need to open new topic?

Comment: Yes, keep it simple, ask just one part. If you need more topics, no problem. Just don't try to put many topics in one question. Ask about the timer, probably will be best option.

Comment: @iansedano may be you can look again? I deleted russian parts and many hard scripts...  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqUmJcTipwKX9Q5m-4dlmXIChp5k1Z98xR2m42GpIT0/edit#gid=0    if it's all the same, I will create new topic