# set a timer between requests from html inputs by withSuccessHandler and onSuccess

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have the problem in html page.

User enters data in html inputs and clicks enter.
After this it must start checking by the function "keyPressFunction" throw withSuccessHandler(onSuccess) to the Google-apps script function  "searchData" in 3 tables on spreadsheet and result must return to var "findData" with true/false. If it true, then focus goes to next input. After third input the data writes to table.

But answer from apps-script returns slowly, near 5 seconds, but the focus is already goes out, when the data is really uncorrect. Can you help me this timer between requests?

For understanding the test project is here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FqUmJcTipwKX9Q5m-4dlmXIChp5k1Z98xR2m42GpIT0/edit#gid=0

and last deployed link of web app is here https://script.google.com/a/fmlogistic.com/macros/s/AKfycbwAcfIVGrbcu24t_6OxtR2gvltG3ojbh1_pNxLed1O8/dev

```js
<script>

  const inputs = document.querySelector('.dws-input');
  const formControl = document.querySelectorAll('.form-control');

  let findData;
  let curInpID;
  let firstValid, secValid, thirdValid, allValid;

  formControl[0].focus();

  function keyPressFunction(ev) {

    let userInfo = {};
    userInfo.login = document.getElementById("tLogin").value;
    userInfo.table = document.getElementById("tTable").value;
    userInfo.order = document.getElementById("tOrder").value;

    let inputData = ev.target.value
    let btnReset = document.getElementById("del");

    if (ev.code !== 'Enter') return;
    if (ev.target.classList.contains("is-valid")) ev.target.classList.remove("is-valid");
    if (ev.target.classList.contains("is-invalid")) ev.target.classList.remove("is-invalid");

    curInpID = ev.target.id;
   
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).searchData(inputData, curInpID);
//the true/false returns here in findData: 

    console.log(findData);

    if (!findData) {   
      ev.target.classList.add("is-invalid");
      ev.target.focus();
      return;
    } else {
      ev.target.classList.add("is-valid");
    };

    btnReset.disabled = (!firstValid == true);

    allValid = (firstValid == true && secValid == true && thirdValid == true) ? true : false;

    for (const i of formControl) {
      if (i.value === '') {
        i.nextElementSibling.focus();
        break;
      }
    }
    
    if (allValid){
      google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
      document.getElementById("tTable").value = '';
      document.getElementById("tOrder").value = '';
      secValid = false;
      thirdValid = false;
      document.getElementById("tTable").focus();
    }
  }

  function onSuccess(_findData) {
    findData = _findData;
    if (!firstValid) firstValid = (findData && curInpID == "tLogin") ? true : false;
    if (!secValid) secValid = (findData && firstValid && curInpID == "tTable") ? true : false;
    if (!thirdValid) thirdValid = (findData && firstValid && secValid && curInpID == "tOrder") ? true : false;
    allValid = (firstValid && secValid && thirdValid) ? true : false;
  }
  
  inputs.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressFunction);

</script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CLR: PACKING</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
       integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>      
</head>
<body>
    <div class="conteiner">
        <form novalidate>
            <h6 class="title">PACKING</h6>
            <div class="dws-input">
                <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                <div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" novalidate id="tLogin" name= "username" placeholder= "Login:" autofocus > 
                        <label for="tLogin">Login:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  novalidate id="tTable" name= "text" placeholder= "Table:" >
                        <label for="tTable">Table:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
                    <input type="text"  novalidate class="form-control" id="tOrder" name= "text" placeholder= "Order:" >
                    <label for="tOrder">Order:</label>
                </div> 
            </div>  
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <?!= include("index-js"); ?>

</body>



</html>
```

at Apps script I have next script:

```js
const url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  let sheetTo = ss.getSheetByName("@sistem");
  let sheetIn = ss.getSheetByName("@packing");
  
function doGet(e){

    var htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
    return htmlServ.evaluate();

}

function userClicked(userInfo){

  sheetIn.appendRow([userInfo.login, userInfo.table, userInfo.order, new Date()]);
  Logger.login(userInfo.name + "clicked the button");
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function searchData(inputData, curInpID){

  var result;
  
  var lrLogins = sheetTo.getRange("A:A").getValues().filter(String).length;
  var arrLogins = sheetTo.getRange(1, 1, lrLogins, 1).getValues().flat();
  
  var lrTMPLORDS = sheetTo.getRange("K:K").getValues().filter(String).length;
  var curTMPLORDS = sheetTo.getRange(1, 11, lrTMPLORDS, 1).getValues();
  
  var lrTABLES = sheetTo.getRange("R:R").getValues().filter(String).length;
  var curTABLES = sheetTo.getRange(1, 18, lrTABLES, 1).getValues().flat();

  if (curInpID == "tLogin"){
    result = (arrLogins.indexOf(inputData) !== -1) ? true : false;
  }
  else if (curInpID == "tTable"){
    result = (curTABLES.indexOf(inputData) !== -1) ? true : false;
  }  
  else if (curInpID == "tOrder"){
    for (i = 0 ; i < curTMPLORDS.length; i ++){
      var regexstring = curTMPLORDS[i];
      var regexp = new RegExp(regexstring, "i");
      var result = regexp.test(inputData);
      if (result) break;
    }
  }
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you look for a way to prevent the user from clicking anything until keyPress Function is return?

Comment: @  Elchanan shuky Shukrun may be, but I don't know, is it really help me?

Comment: @Cooper thank you, can you show me examples? I'm newbe at this...((

Comment: @ Cooper  I need set timeout for disabling inputs while returning answer from server. I had the recommendation from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68846957/convert-asynchronous-onsuccess-into-a-promise-and-do-await?noredirect=1#comment121801003_68846957 to create new topic with question about timer or something like this.

Comment: @Cooper sorry, but pushing me from one way to way on this site is incredible issue for me. I have brainstorm about this...

Comment: @Cooper sorry for language. I'm not expert in English. But it's not clear to me how can I disable inputs while my html page is waiting answer from server. And I have different answers from this site users on the same question...

Comment: @ Cooper  problem is my knowledge level. prevent users from entering new data before answer returns - I don't know how to do that. but the question is about setting timeout and not about disabling and Html events...

Comment: @Cooper the reality is then user will try to write the RIGHT value several times and to click Enter before next input will be enable with "true" if previous answer was "false". And the reality is that the procedure will take place on a mobile scanner, where the procedure scanning includes writing and clicking Enter. I think your idea is not bad and sure I will try it that but also I would like to have a fallback with timer))

Comment: Can you please provide more information on what do you want to accomplish? I don't quite understand your explanation in the post.

Comment: @ Iamblichus what exactly did you not understand?

Comment: @ can anyone help me with question in this theme? I'm not expert in script, sorry, I really don't know what is need to edit here or write...

Comment: I didn't understand what's the desired workflow and what's going wrong with it. I understand the user is supposed to press one key, which will call a server-side function that will return true or false. Some questions would be: is it returning the correct value? What does `focus` and `input` mean in this context? What does `After third input the data writes to table.` mean? What does `but the focus is already goes out, when the data is really uncorrect` mean?

Comment: @Iamblichus yes, the it's returning correct value, but returning is slowly becasuse it is asynchronous. "After third input the data writes to table". - I think the writing to the table is different topic, so you can do not pay attention.

Comment: @Iamblichus "focus is already goes out, when the data is really uncorrect" - in my script here is function with going focus between the inputs by clicking Enter. but while the "google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).searchData(inputData, curInpID)" 
is getting the true/false value from server in var findData, the cursor can already go to the next input. The problem of this topic about this.

Comment: may be I can put recursion in function keyPressFunction(ev)  after google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).searchData(inputData, curInpID)? Or may be I can put pause in script for waiting answer from server after clicking Enter?

Comment: So the issue would be about avoiding the event `inputs.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressFunction);` to run while the server function `searchData` hasn't returned and `onSuccess` hasn't executed yet?

Comment: @ Iamblichus I think this is right description)) can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

If I understand you correctly, you want to avoid the `keydown` events to execute `keyPressFunction` while the server-side function `searchData` hasn't still returned the data.

#### Solution:

If that's the case, I'd suggest you to use [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) at the start of the `keyPressFunction` (in order to avoid successive `keydown` event to trigger more executions of this function), and add it again via [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) when executing you success handler function (`onSuccess`).

It could be something along the following lines:

```
function keyPressFunction(ev) {
  inputs.removeEventListener('keydown', keyPressFunction);
  // ... REST OF YOUR FUNCTION
}

function onSuccess(_findData) {
  // ... REST OF YOUR FUNCTION
  inputs.addEventListener('keydown', keyPressFunction);
}
```

#### Update:

`keyPressFunction` finishes execution without calling the server-function `searchData` if the pressed key is not `Enter`. Since the event will only be reactivated after `searchData` returns and `onSuccess` runs, it will not be reactivated if the pressed key is not `Enter`. Because of this, `keyPressFunction` will only run once (if the pressed key is not `Enter`).

In order to avoid this, move the `removeEventListener` line to just before calling `searchData`:

```
function keyPressFunction(ev) {
  // ... REST OF YOUR FUNCTION
  inputs.removeEventListener('keydown', keyPressFunction);
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).searchData(inputData, curInpID);
}
```

**Sidenote**: Please note that everything that is written in `keyPressFunction` after calling `searchData` will never be executed, since the execution will be moved to the failure or success handlers (`onSuccess` in your case). So move that on top of the mentioned line (starting with `google.script.run`) if you want it to run.

#### Reference:

- [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236766/discussion-on-answer-by-iamblichus-set-a-timer-between-requests-from-html-inputs).